# linux: find common files from two directories with single command

Tags: linux, directory, find

Dir1:  `[anyName]-test/target/surefire-reports/*.xml`

Dir2:  `target/surefire-reports/*.xml`

jenkins shell cmd i came up:

```
sh "jar -cMvf  Test.zip target/surefire-reports/*.xml *-test/target/surefire-reports/*.xml "
```

only one directory exists ( dir1 or dir2), so the shell step always fails for no file or directory.

Any better idea to look for xml files, in single command, without failing ?  (may be some regular expression) Thanks !

Comment: edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `find`:

```
find . -type f -regex '\./\([^/]*-test/\)?target/surefire-reports/[^/]*\.xml'\
  -exec jar -cMvf Test.zip {} +
```

The `-regex` action matches the path of your regular (`type -f`) files. This will only add `*.xml` files from the `surefire-reports` directories, not from its subdirectories. If you want to include subdirectories, replace `[^/]*\.xml` with `.*\.xml`.

---

Alternative using glob patterns:

```
find target/surefire-reports *-test/target/surefire-reports -maxdepth 1 -type f\
  -name '*.xml' -exec jar -cMvf Test.zip {} +
```

If you want to include subdirectories, remove `-maxdepth 1`.

Run both commands from the parent directory of `target` (your project dir).

Comment: really appreciate your help. Both solutions works just fine from both Dir1 and Dir2 .  for me solution 1 is what i want :) .        Since the alternative option will always fail in shell , with  No such file or directory , as it looks for two directories same time and only one directory exists for me.   I will go with solution 1.   Thanks a lot for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cd <TOP DIRECTORY>
find . -type f -name "*unitTest.xml" -print | xargs jar -cMvf Test.zip
```

I put "*unitTest.xml since in Dir2 the `J` is in caps.
This way it will capture the JUnitTtest.xml files only if they exist.

So the results of the `find` command are used as arguments to the `jar` command.  This is done by `xargs`.  `find` does not care if the file is there or not, so no error.

Tested on bash.

Comment: Thanks, its almost ok, but those xml files exists in other folders also, so i don't need them.    
 I want from    "(anyfolder)-test/target/surefire-reports/*.xml "   OR    "target/surefire-reports/*.xml"